# Dynamic ListView in multiple screens

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm developing a dynamic ListView to support multiple screens and devices and i don't want it to scroll horizontally, assume that i have a 8 columns list, without scrolling, how can i show my list in different devices , 8 columns would not completely view-able on 3.5 inch devices.any suggestion would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Either change the way you display list items to make them fit a normal phone screen, or use something other than ListView.